# Jest -- Proper way to write test descriptions

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This may seem pedantic but I'm asking from a learner's perspective.

The syntax of the `it` helper lends itself to the syntax

```
it('should behave in this certain way...')
```

and most all the coders I know insist on writing 'should' for every single test.

To me this is a subtle but annoying pet peeve because the whole point of `it` is to save me keystrokes -- if it comes with the requirement to type `should` for every test it seems like an utter waste of a shortcut.

Is it a best practice to write `it('should...')` or can  we simply write `it('behaves in this expected way')`?

Serious question -- I'm losing my mind over this little detail.

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/should-up

Comment: Bruno, kindly post that as the answer and I'll give you the green checkmark. Very grateful for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an opinion based question, but I found myself writing a lot of `should`s in the past, until I found a spotify repository that changed my testing life

[Should up](https://github.com/spotify/should-up) is a CLI that removes `should`s from your tests and they explain in the README.md why and how you should write tests.

Basically it just removes a lot of text that is just redundant and makes everything easier to read.

Comment: Well appreciated @BrunoLM -- there is a constant torment we face as developers when it comes to these details. Also 'commit messages should be written in the imperative' which ought to be taught in first year

Comment: @AlexandrosK about commit messages, check this https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/